# Useful information for a self made DnD gamemaster screen

Tags: dnd-5e, tools

I am currently working on a hand-crafted gamemaster screen made out of wood for a good friend of mine. I am planning on not using the DnD 5e "orignal" GM Screen as inlay, but creating a unique layout. Since I am not that well versed in D&D I am now wondering which information would be good and useful for the DM that might be needed during campaigns.

I was also thinking of adding some blank boxes with headings, where the DM might write some Information that is useful for him depending on the campaign (this would of course be erasable since I am going to foil the inlay to be then written on with whiteboard markers).

Any suggestions for the pre-written information and the blank boxes to be written on are very appreciated. 
Also any additional advice or ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[What sort of cheat sheets should a new DM have for a better flowing 5e game of Dungeons and Dragons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60386)"

Comment: The most useful information is what **you** are most likely to forget. Hard to answer without knowing you.

Comment: Well, since this screen is not for me, my question is rather what should most definetely be on the screen, and what kind of information might be added by the DM him/herself. Knowing the latter i could more closely design the free space as needed with the correct size and fit for the additional info.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you review the question this is marked as a duplicate of and see whether it matches your question?