# Cheat Sheets for DMing 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I've seen some wonderful DM screen cheat sheets for 5e... Might anyone know of any good ones for 3.5 at all? I'm about to embark on my 1st attempt at DMing, for our son and his friends.
Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, product recommendations are considered "shopping"-type questions, which are no longer allowed here. Your question might be [better suited to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: @V2Blast Is there a question in here that would be acceptable, like *What kind of information should be on a* D&D 3.5 *quick-reference sheet?*

Comment: @HeyICanChan: That might be acceptable, but I generally leave that determination to the community. A question of that sort for 5e has stayed open: [What sort of cheat sheets should a new DM have for a better flowing 5e game of Dungeons and Dragons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60386/what-sort-of-cheat-sheets-should-a-new-dm-have-for-a-better-flowing-5e-game-of-d)

Comment: @V2Blast Cool. I hope the asker considers revising the question so as to be more like that one. (*Full Disclosure:* I have my homemade *D&D 3.5* cheat sheet sitting in front of me.)